# VS2013 C++ Compiler Mangling name defined with extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, ftdi, extern-c

I'm trying to build a WIN32 console app that uses the current 2.12.28 ftd2xx.lib static library from FTDI.  I'm using VS2013 and native unmanaged C++.  My call looks like this.

```
#include "../ftd2xx.h"
 . . .
    DWORD port_count = 0;
    FT_STATUS status = FT_OK;
    status = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&port_count);
```

When I compile I get a link error

```
GetTopazVCP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList@4 referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl Get1stVirtualComPort(unsigned long *)" (?Get1stVirtualComPort@@YAKPAK@Z)
```

The unresolved symbol **__imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList@4** appears to be a mangled name version of the **FT_CreateDeviceInfoList** function.  So it's not being resolved in the ftd2xx.lib which uses C naming.  What I don't understand is why the compiler mangled the name when the ftd2xx.h file has a conditional extern "C"

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif
. . .
FTD2XX_API
    FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(
    LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs
    );
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

wrapping all the FT_??? declarations.  I have confirmed that __cplusplus is defined during the compile.  Any ideas what is causing the unexpected name mangling?

Comment: It is linking error. Are you sure you have added ftd2xx.lib library in to your project?

Comment: The `imp` prefix denotes the function's code is **imp**orted from a DLL (rather than a static library), and the `@n` is just a part of the function name (because it uses Microsoft's `__stdcall` calling convention instead of the normal C calling convention (`__cdecl`); that's what the `WINAPI` macro means in the function declaration). In other words, there is no C++ name mangling happening here, and you just have a normal linker error, presumably because you're missing a library in your project's linker settings.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I was coming to the conclusion that it wasn't name mangling after I switched the calling source file from C++ to standard C and got the same error.  I was linking the static library but apparently the header file I was using was for the DLL version.  I replaced the ftd2xx.lib file with the DLL version and it compiled successfully.  Looking at ftd2xx.h, if you want to use static library you need to #define FTD2XX_STATIC before #include "ftd2xx.h"

Comment: Note - the @... suffix indicates the number of bytes used on the stack for input parameters, in this case @4 for a 4 byte or 32 bit parameter.

Comment: Not called "mangling", exported C functions are decorated.  This is the stdcall decoration, the @4 postfix indicates the size of bytes of the passed arguments.  It helps the linker to detect calling convention mismatches, only happens in 32-bit code.  The imp prefix tells you that it is not a function at all, it is a variable.  It points to the function at runtime, helps the OS loader to generate slightly faster code when it binds the function.  This is otherwise a plain old linker error, invariably produced by forgetting to link the correct library, sometimes by a declaration mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ChronoKitsune pointed out in his comment there is no name mangling here.  The problem was I was linking the static version of the FTDI library but the default for the ftd2xx.h header file is to declare the FT_??? functions as calls to the DLL version.  When I replaced the ftd2xx.lib static version with the ftd2xx.lib DLL version it built successfully.  FTDI only supplies one version of the ftd2xx.h header and looking closely inside it I discovered that if you want to use the static ftd2xx.lib you need to #define FTD2XX_STATIC before including ftd2xx.h

```
#define FTD2XX_STATIC
#include "ftd2xx.h"
```